# "Synchronize Grails Settings" does not work (intellij 14)

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

We have had this problem with all versions of intellij right up to 14.1.3.
When you click on

Grails->Synchronize Grails Settings

nothing happens.  Nothing is executed, the cursor does not change, and, importantly, there is no way to get Intellij to recognize that your configuration has changed (e.g. if you change the version of an existing plugin defined in your buildConfig.groovy).

This is a huge problem.

Interestingly, it works on a MAC with identical project, intellij and java version version.

I don't expect an answer or resolution - but if anyone else gets the same problem, it would be nice to know we are not the only ones.

The grails project consists of the application, and a number of exploded plugins.  Everything else works fine.

Project structure:

```
mainApp
  grails-app
  :
plugin1
  grails-app
  :
plugin2
```

It was imported into intellij by doing a "grails integrate-with --intellij" in the mainApp dir, then simply opening the resultant ipr file in intellij.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with intellij 14 with some of my projects. it works for some modules and not for others

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Select the module which has dependency issue.
2. Click F4 (module settings)
3. Click on modules in left side (project settings)
4. Click on dependencies tab on right side
5. Verify all the inline plugin modules that your module depends on are there in dependencies, if not, add them by clicking  + and selecting module dependency

Comment: They were missing. Its a shame that intillij on windows has no way to syncronise the grails settings - it has to be done by hand.  Our mac devs using intelij have no such issues with the same project.